# AWS Step Functions & Athena integration: Can I invoke a cross region query?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-athena, aws-step-functions

I have an AWS Step Function's State Machine in us-east-1 and I want to run a sync job in Athena in us-west-2 via [Athena Optimized Integration feature](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/connect-athena.html).
Is that possible?

I have the right IAM role, do not mention it.

for lambda functions it would be as simple as put the ARN (which includes the target region) but for Athena the documented ARN is `arn:aws:states:::athena:startQueryExecution.sync` which skips the region. Can I just fill the region there?